# How to add Clone and Copy functions in mocking MongoDB in Go?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I read this [article](http://thylong.com/golang/2016/mocking-mongo-in-golang/) and it has good guides for mocking MongoDB in Go. But there are some problems in `Clone()` and `Copy()` methods.
I create this interfaces and structs:

```
type ISession interface {
    DB(name string) IDatabase
    Close()
    Clone() ISession
    Copy() ISession
}

type IDatabase interface {
    C(name string) ICollection
}

type MongoSession struct {
    dbSession *mgo.Session
}

func (s MongoSession) DB(name string) IDatabase {
    return &MongoDatabase{Database: s.dbSession.DB(name)}
}

func (s MongoSession) Clone() ISession {
    //return session.clone
    return s.dbSession.Clone()
}

func (s MongoSession) Copy() ISession {
    return s.dbSession.Copy()
}
```

But I got this error

> cannot use s.dbSession.Clone() (type *mgo.Session) as type ISession in
>   return argument:  *mgo.Session does not implement ISession (wrong type
>   for Clone method)         have Clone() *mgo.Session       want Clone() ISession
>
> cannot use s.dbSession.Copy() (type *mgo.Session) as type ISession in
>   return argument:  *mgo.Session does not implement ISession (wrong type
>   for Clone method)         have Clone() *mgo.Session       want Clone() ISession

How can I add `Clone()` and `Copy()` methods to interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MongoSession.Copy()` and `MongoSession.Clone()` must return a value that implements `ISession`. Basically you create `MongoSession` type exactly for this: to implement `ISession`.

[`mgo.Session`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Session) does not implement your `ISession` interface (e.g. because its [`Session.Clone()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Session.Clone) method has a return type of `*mgo.Session` and not `ISession`). You should create and return a new value of `MongoSession`, in which you can wrap the copied or cloned `*mgo.Session` value.

Like this:

```
func (s MongoSession) Clone() ISession {
    return MongoSession{dbSession: s.dbSession.Clone()}
}

func (s MongoSession) Copy() ISession {
    return MongoSession{dbSession: s.dbSession.Copy()}
}
```

Comment: Thnx. It Works.  Is it correct way for mocking MongoDB in Go? Another question is each time I call Copy method it return new object. Isn't this cause a problem?

Comment: This kind of mocking isn't necessarily the best solution, but it's a working, viable solution.

Comment: And calling `Copy()` does not cause trouble as long as you don't forget to close the copy with its `Close()` method when you're done with it. But you must close it!